# Strip string into lines and find specific line within the char range in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, char, line

The goal is to trim a string in lines and select the exactly line where the specific range is.
How can this be done using iterators in rust?

```rust
let my_string = "Some small words, they're this.\nTogether";
let stripped_lines = ["Some small words, they\'re this.", "Together"];
// Important word where the char is located with inclusive range

range = Range {start: 33, end:41}
let chosen_line = "Together"
```

The `\n` is considered to be the delimiter for a new line and `\` shall not be considered, as it is formatting.

What I have tried so far:

```rust
let chosen_line = my_string.lines()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(lineno, content)| (lineno + 1, content))
    .skip_while(|(lineno, _)| range.start < lineno)
    .take_while(|(lineno, _)| range.end >= lineno)
    .map(|(_, content)| content)
    .collect::<Vec<&'_ str>>();
```

This did not work. I do not know how to combine the logic of enumerating lines and choosing char constraint.

Please consider that the range is restricted to a specific line and will never be between lines (starting and finishing in different lines)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I have added something tried but could not progress with ideas. Maybe find char and come back till find the \n backwards...

Comment: A couple of things aren't clear to me.

1. As `char` has a specific meaning in Rust, what do you mean by "choosing  the `char` constraint", are you looking for a specific string of text in the given lines, e.g. `"f"` or `"foo"`, returning the line numbers for where this string occurs? 

2. If the pattern occurs more than once in the given text, should the line for the first occurrence be returned or something else?

Comment: I am looking for a line which includes an specific range from the original string which in this case would be 33 till 41. The pattern can occur more than once because it is range from the first string. Consider that this range is only included in a line specific \n surrounded by.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the line which some character (by byte index) is on by counting how many newlines come before it:

```
string[..index].chars().filter(|x| x == '\n').count()
```

What do you want to happen, if the range start and end are not in the single line?
Do you want an error, a range of line indices, or just the index of the range start?
You can just compute both and handle the case of differing lines appropriately if needed.

NB:
If you need multiple lookups in the same string, the above might be slow for large strings. You can precompute a list of newlines once (which you store together with the string) and then use binary search:

```
// once:
let newlines = string.char_indices().filter_map(|(ix,c)| if c == '\n' {Some(ix)} else {None}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
// for each lookup:
newlines.binary_search(&index).unwrap_or_else(|x| x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understood your question correctly and what you want to do is to get all lines containing substring of symbols from multiline text:

1. Get substring [33..41] to match against
   This is ugly, but I don't know another way to get char slice of string without pulling dependencies

```
    let my_string = "Some small words, they're this.\nTogether";
    let stripped_lines = ["Some small words, they\'re this.", "Together"];

    let substring = my_string
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(i, c)| match (33..41).contains(&i) {
            true => Some(c),
            false => None,
        })
        .collect::<String>();
```

2. Filter_map array of lines to lines containing substring

```
    let chosen_line: String = stripped_lines
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|l| match l.contains(&substring) {
            true => Some(String::from(*l)),
            false => None,
        })
        .collect();
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1238e6f511807e9a61b9e1277f38de8a)